# qvariant as key in qhash

Tags: qt, key, qvariant, qhash

I want to create a data structure with QVariants a keys. It looks like this:

```
QHash<QPair<QVariant, QVariant>, SHAPES::Shape* > _shapes;
```

Unfortunately there is "no matching function for call to ‘qHash(const QVariant&)’".

So I defined my own implementation of qHash for QVariants:

```
#pragma once

#include <QVariant>
#include <QHash>

uint qHash( const QVariant & var )
{
    if ( !var.isValid() || var.isNull() )
        //return -1;
        Q_ASSERT(0);

    switch ( var.type() )
    {
        case QVariant::Int:
                return qHash( var.toInt() );
            break;
        case QVariant::UInt:
                return qHash( var.toUInt() );
            break;
        case QVariant::Bool:
                return qHash( var.toUInt() );
            break;
        case QVariant::Double:
                return qHash( var.toUInt() );
            break;
        case QVariant::LongLong:
                return qHash( var.toLongLong() );
            break;
        case QVariant::ULongLong:
                return qHash( var.toULongLong() );
            break;
        case QVariant::String:
                return qHash( var.toString() );
            break;
        case QVariant::Char:
                return qHash( var.toChar() );
            break;
        case QVariant::StringList:
                return qHash( var.toString() );
            break;
        case QVariant::ByteArray:
                return qHash( var.toByteArray() );
            break;
        case QVariant::Date:
        case QVariant::Time:
        case QVariant::DateTime:
        case QVariant::Url:
        case QVariant::Locale:
        case QVariant::RegExp:
                return qHash( var.toString() );
            break;
        case QVariant::Map:
        case QVariant::List:
        case QVariant::BitArray:
        case QVariant::Size:
        case QVariant::SizeF:
        case QVariant::Rect:
        case QVariant::LineF:
        case QVariant::Line:
        case QVariant::RectF:
        case QVariant::Point:
        case QVariant::PointF:
            // not supported yet
            break;
        case QVariant::UserType:
        case QVariant::Invalid:
        default:
            return -1;
    }

    // could not generate a hash for the given variant
    return -1;
}
```

But then the compiler says, that the method is defined multiple times.

So, how to use QVariant as keys in QHash? Or: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to put the function definition before `QHash` include.

Comment: I have no problem compiling: QHash<QPair<QVariant, QVariant*>, QVariant > _shapes;

Comment: @asclepix What version of Qt are you running?  I can't see a `qHash(QVariant)` in either 4.8 or 5.0.

Comment: well, in my case adding `inline` to the definition and include `QHash` before the definition worked out

Comment: Qt 4.8.1 on Linux (gcc version 4.6.3)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your `qHash` implementation is placed in a header file. You need to declare it in header file without implementation:

```
uint qHash( const QVariant & var );
```

Implementation should be placed in the respective source file.

Also note that `qHash()` declaration should be placed before `#include <QHash>`.

Comment: The requirement that 
uint qHash( const QVariant & var );
has to go before
#include <QHash>
is really nasty because even if you don't include QHash, if you include a header that includes QHash somewhere down the line, then the code won't compile. I was able to work around this by including that class first, and forward declaring the qHash function.

Comment: Wow, I can't understand the requirement for the definition of qHash before the inclusion of the header. And I agree that it is pretty nasty.

Comment: The placement of `qHash()` before the include doesn't seem to be necessary with Qt 4.7.4 on Linux (GCC 4.4 and above).