# Can't export from dll symbols that are perfectly valid otherwise

Tags: c++, qt, templates, winapi, dllexport

I realized an application under Linux:

- using mostly Qt as library;
- consisting of several libraries and a main gui application.

And as I'm making my code compliant to Visual Studio 2015's compiler I stumbled on the following dllexport problem (it is in fact a snipped code):

```
#include <QVariant>
#include <QList>

class SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT Snipped : public QList<QVariant>
{

public:
  Snipped();
};
```

SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT being the classical:

```
#if defined(SNIPPED_LIBRARY)
#  define SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

That code generating:

```
C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qhashfunctions.h:110: erreur : C2665: 'qHash': none of the 22 overloads could convert all the argument types
C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qhashfunctions.h:110: erreur : C2056: illegal expression
```

The error message is explicit enough and I even found people that have defined their own qHash:

- http://www.qtforum.org/article/19733/qmultihash-qvariant-compiler-error-c2665.html
- [qvariant as key in qhash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208813/qvariant-as-key-in-qhash)

What is troubling me:

- I'm using QList and not qHash direcly; I'm well aware that QList may use qHash internally but the code runs smoothly with gcc: so it seems that Qt is providing what is required;
- when I build the exact class in a regular binary (not a library one), all runs perfectly (either windows or linux).
- when I removed the `__declspec`, then the library is building perfectly

I took time to read documentations about exporting templates as it seems the real problem (I even took time to read Qt source code (hey, their code is running :-))):

- using Explicit template instantiation: [here](https://anteru.net/blog/2008/11/19/318/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx)
- digging up some history bit: [How to export an instantiation of a Standard Template Library (STL) class and a class that contains a data member that is an STL object](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958)

But the described problem doesn't seem to apply. I tried all kind of combinations but none did the trick (and it would have been a fluke).

The code being so short and simple, I think that I missed something basic (sorry: it is not really an interesting question and it is fustrating).

Has someone an idea?

P.S.: Full technical data:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, with the last update: 14.0.25424.00 Update 3
- Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA285
- Using the Windows Kit 10: 10.0.10586.0
- creation of an library project through QtCreator
- snipped.pro

  ```
  QT       -= gui
  TARGET   = snipped
  TEMPLATE = lib
  DEFINES += SNIPPED_LIBRARY
  SOURCES += snipped.cpp
  ```
- snipped.cpp

  ```
  #include "snipped.h"
  #include <QDebug>

  Snipped::Snipped()
  {
    qDebug("Coucou !");/*some code is required otherwise the build will generate nothing*/
  }
  ```
- snipped.h

  ```
  #ifndef SNIPPED_H
  #define SNIPPED_H

  #include "snipped_global.h"
  #include <QVariant>
  #include <QList>

  class SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT Snipped : public QList<QVariant>
  {
  public:
    Snipped();
  };

  #endif // SNIPPED_H
  ```
- snipped_global.h

  ```
  #ifndef SNIPPED_GLOBAL_H
  #define SNIPPED_GLOBAL_H

  #include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

  #if defined(SNIPPED_LIBRARY)
  #  define SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define SNIPPEDSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif

  #endif // SNIPPED_GLOBAL_H
  ```

Comment: Solved. 
Explanations are in the original question.

Comment: Can you remove the answer from the question, and create it as a separate answer please?  Note: It is *perfectly* acceptable to answer your own question - in fact it is encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why I had this problem on « [Microsoft Specific](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx) »: 
I quote:

> When you declare a class dllexport, **all** its member functions and
>   static data members are exported. You must provide the definitions of
>   all such members in the same program.  Otherwise, a linker error is
>   generated.

And in order to be complete:

> The one exception to this rule applies to pure virtual functions, for
>   which you need not provide explicit definitions. However, because a
>   destructor for an abstract class is always called by the destructor
>   for the base class, pure virtual destructors must always provide a
>   definition. Note that these rules are the same for nonexportable
>   classes.
>
> If you export data of class type or functions that return classes, be
>   sure to export the class.

It will teach me not to glance over the documentation.